# Authenticate a Firebase user on Puppeteer via JWT token

Tags: firebase, jwt, puppeteer

We are creating a PDF generating service and want to create a PDF of a secure view.
We're using Firebase Auth on the frontend and tried to use generated a JWT token to avoid using headless login (username/password).

What is the recommended way to inject the JWT token from Firebase into Puppeteer in order to authenticated the current session?

Comment: Have you found out any solution ? I'm actually looking to do the exact same thing

Comment: Yes, setting the correct cookie was the solution. Checkout the cookie in an existing Firebase app and copy it. I think you can even generate it yourself.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a snippet? I'm not sure I follow .. as far as I can tell, Firebase uses indexedDB nowadays, not cookies or localstorage, but puppeteer does not have idb access / support. I tried via injecting code (evaluate), but it doesn't work either ... please advise.